# Getting my gps location while I'm offline

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

I've doing some research about getting my gps position. I'm using google maps API v2 so in order to get my current position I used this

```
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders();
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
```

so from my understanding there is a list in the `locationManager` and `getLastKnowLocation()` returns the last entry from that list. Also if this list is not empty I can get the last entry while my application is offline.

I happened to have my wifi off for the weekend and checked to see if it works but no location was returned to me.

**So my first question is**: how long are the entries in the list available for my application to retrieve them provided there is no internet connection for a while.

Also the location that I will be retrieving will be the last which was fixed while I was online correct? so even If I can retrieve it, it won't be accurate so  is there another way to get my current gps location while my cell is offline? (ie via gps or gsm network)
Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can keep the location updates in DB with time stamp so that later you can fetch this.

Comment: yes but they will still be outdated if I'm offline for a while

Comment: Whenever you get a location update, jus keep that location in preference or DB then how it become outdated? i didn't get you clearly pls

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't have to be connected to internet to get location updates through GPS. If your device supports GPS, it will get connected to the GPS satellites if your outdoors and you can get the location updates through GPS. [Read this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER) to know how to use location providers. 


Also be informed that if the provider is not turned on, getLastKnownLocation() will always return null. Quoting from android documentaion,

> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

Comment: yes but getting location via gps requires the user to be outdoors and it also might take up to 15minutes. Is there any other faster way while I'm not online?

Comment: Well it's not something I can foretell. I generally need location updates whether I'm in or outdoors. The factor is how quickly I can get them