# Using Google play service can i get latest location in offline mode ( FusedLocationProviderApi)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

using google play service we can get `getLastLocation()` which are using fused location provider to retrieve the device's last known location.
using change location i can set `setPriority()`
know to get current location form google doc

**Once you have connected to Google Play services and the location services API, you can get the current location settings of a user's device**

so my question is if i am not connected to network (internet connection) can i use the latest location of user not the last location the current location

Comment: yes if you turn on the gps you can get the latest location without internet connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting my gps location while I'm offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380188/getting-my-gps-location-while-im-offline)

Comment: mallaudin if am not using LocationManger class , i am using fused API get location From LocationServices so if i have no internet connection how should be able to get the location as i am  fused API get location from google play services  as LocationManger is not very good in door

Answer (score 0):

yes sure you can get latest update location using `GoogleApiClient`. check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).
It has worked for me.Thank you.

Comment: if you want then tell me so i will post example. @Nouman Shah

Comment: please if it is easy for you

Comment: yes fused api when there is no internet connection and i want current location

Comment: I don't think you can used fused api without internet.  @NoumanShah